# Scheduled reminders working for some but not all

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

Drupal 7.41, Civi 4.6.9

The scheduled reminders are working except for 1 or 2 per day might not be sent.  It appears random which ones don't get the reminder sent.  The 1 or 2 a day is based on a rather small sample size.  This client doesn't have all that many memberships so it's usually 5 or less reminders for any given day.  Sometimes none are sent.

I have looked at the members/memberships that don't get reminders and I have not been able to find a reason those members didn't get a reminder while others have on that same day.  If anyone has experience with this I would sure appreciate any help you might have.

Comment: can you make sure you have a primary Email ID for the missed member and also look for these flag are not set against the contact like (do not mail)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I did check both those conditions and the ones that didn't receive reminders had a primary email and no communications flags checked.  It is interesting that all of them were supposed to receive the reminders 30 days out.  I will have to see if they get the 15 day reminder.

Comment: [CRM-15461](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15461), [CRM-15728](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15728) and [CRM-17880](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17880) now seem to relate to this. The "Related" sidebar for this question suggests that Scheduled Reminders might be a tricky area for lots of sites!

Comment: Yes, I am responsible for #17880 actually.  I describe the problem and fix in that issue but to condense things the fix is:  in CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php there is a query that needs to be modified.  I changed line 1257 to $dateClause = "{$startDate}";  It's been working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a bug and I have submitted an issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17880.

Basically, if there is a previous entry in the civicrm_action_log (like from last year) with the same action_schedule_id (same reminder) no new reminder is sent.